# Is PowerShell included in Windows Vista?

Tags: windows-vista, powershell

Is any version of PowerShell included in "vanilla" installation of Windows Vista? Or must it be downloaded/installed separately?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not.

PowerShell 1.0 is an optional component for Windows 2008 and PowerShell 2.0 is part of Windows 2008 R2 and Windows 7.

For Vista, you need to download it separately, although I think 2.0 is offered through Windows Update as an optional Download.